# A stationary distribution of Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

For a irreducible finite Markov chain, I know that the definition of a stationary distribution is as follows:

$\pi P = \pi$, where $P$ is a transition matrix and $\pi$ is a stationary distribution (as a vector).

Based on the definition above, I was wondering if the following definition can be valid for a stationary distribution.

$\pi_j = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{m=1} Pr\{X_m = j\}$

That is, are the two definitions equivalent? If so, could you please give me some links (or books) in order to check out their relationship?

Comment: Your question comes down to: do the sequence of arithmetic means of the distributions over time converge to the stationary distribution for a finite, irreducible, *periodic* Markov chain. In the aperiodic case the distributions themselves converge by a standard theorem, and you don't need any averaging. In the periodic case I think it still works, but I am not sure whether it is possible for a Markov matrix to have eigenvalues with modulus $1$ which are not roots of unity. (Deterministic cycles, i.e. Markov matrices which are permutation matrices, give roots of unity as eigenvalues.)

Comment: @Ian you need averaging even in aperiodic case if you want to estimate/produce $\pi$. I think this method of explicitly constructing/estimating $\pi$ should be more emphasized.

Comment: @A.S. You need to average trajectories but you do not need to average distributions in the aperiodic case.

Comment: @ian of course. I'm noting the computational/constructive aspect. Simply producing samples from $\pi_0P^n$ (which converges to $\pi$ by itself) while discarding trajectories that led to it is wasteful. It's better to run one chains for a long time than many chains for a short time (given a limit on the number of samples).

Comment: @ian Could you please give me some references? Though I've seen $\pi P = \pi$ and time reversibility to verify an invariant distribution, I've never seen the method of the sequence of arithmetic means of the distributions over time. If possible, I want to know their relationship mathematically. Thanks.

Comment: @user227924 Being invariant is just $\pi P = \pi$. Just irreducibility guarantees that there is only one such $\pi$. But if you have periodicity, then you may not converge to this $\pi$ from certain initial distributions. The problem is that although all eigenvalues of $P$ have modulus at most $1$, and the eigenvalue $1$ is simple, there can be other eigenvalues of modulus $1$.

Comment: @user227924 For instance $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$. For another example, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues given by the three complex cube roots of unity. The contributions from these eigenvalues with modulus $1$ do not decay when you take powers. (Think of the sequence $(-1)^n$.) But because of cancellations, the contributions from these eigenvalues *do* decay when you take arithmetic means. (Think of the sequence $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k$.)